# Where to put the completionHandler in my function Swift 3

Tags: swift, completionhandler

I have been trying to learn about completion handlers in Swift, but can't seem to find the answer to my question. If I have multiple completion handlers, do they have to be in exclusive places? For example, can I have the code:

```
func example(x:Int, completionHandler: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> ()){
   if x > 5 {
      completionHandler(true)
   }
   completionHandler(false)
}
```

Or do I have to enclose the `completionHandler(false)` within an else statement (eg. do completion handlers have to be in exclusive spots from each other)? If so, can someone explain how the above scenario would play out? The way I comprehend completion handlers as "return values" after all the code within a function has finished executing. So would the above scenario have 2 different "return values"?

Also, what would happen if I did not include that second completionHandler, and `x = 4`? How would that affect the code that calls this function?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try it in a Playground.

Comment: I'll try that. I didn't realize I could do that cause my code that required the completion handler was using Firebase! Forgot I could dumb the example down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, if you pass `6` as the first argument, your [closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) will execute twice:

1. When you get the **true** in the condition block;
2. When the closure is called as an escaping one.

As an example, I wrote a one-method class, which demonstrates a closure's behavior by printing the passed argument as result.

You can see the results below
[image]

Comment: If you get rid of the line `completionHandler(false)`, and you pass `x = 4`, the function will never hit the first completion handler. What happens then? I tried it out, and it kind of grayed out the `(2 times)` on the side. Does that mean it just doesn't execute the closure?

Comment: @kbunarjo if you pass `4` as x, u get false result into if condition block and you won't get into the if body. So, doesn't matter, what will be into the if body block, you first method argument will be less or equal than five.

Comment: @kbunarjo after `if` block, you will continue to move forward from the method. And if u remove second completion handler, you just return from this method, because your completion handler never called before.